# How can I enable strong private key protection programmatically in C#?

Tags: c#, certificate

How can I achieve the equivalent of setting the "strong private key protection" checkbox in certmgr.msc when adding an X509Certificate2 programmatically using C#?

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this - I'm in the same situation? I see it can be done on import, but it really should be the export file which carries this setting...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to setup the [`X509KeyStorageFlags`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509keystorageflags.aspx) accordingly when [importing the certificate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms148400.aspx) (i.e. `MachineKeySet` and `UserProtected`).