# Add a certificate to store with high level security settings

Tags: c#, certificate, x509certificate

There is a post here [How can I install a certificate into the local machine store programmatically using c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566570/how-can-i-install-a-certificate-into-the-local-machine-store-programmatically-us) about how to add to a store.

But there's no option for setting high level security (requesting a password each time a certificate is used). How to do that ?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913971/how-can-i-enable-strong-private-key-protection-programmatically-in-c

Comment: That's a feature of the certificate, not the store.

Comment: @IanGilroy yes thanks couldn't find it at first